# The .host:/ do not show the shared directory name

Tags: centos, vmware-player

I follow this VMware shared directory [settings up tutorial](https://alexandrerosseto.medium.com/vmware-linux-how-to-share-folder-between-host-and-vm-62e63419ecbb):

when I get to this step:

> sudo vmhgfs-fuse .host:/shared /mnt/hgfs/shared -o allow_other -o uid=1000

then I want to check the files below `.host:/`

when I double click <kbd>`shift`</kbd>, I didn't see the `shared` directory:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls .host:/
bin/   dev/   home/  lib64/ mnt/   proc/  run/   srv/   tmp/   var/   
boot/  etc/   lib/   media/ opt/   root/  sbin/  sys/   usr/
```

Answer (score 0):

The command syntax of

```
sudo vmhgfs-fuse .host:/shared /mnt/hgfs/shared -o allow_other -o uid=1000
```

mimics the usage of the `mount` command with NFS shares.

The `.host:/shared` specifies the "remote" location of the share that is to be mounted to `/mnt/hgfs/shared` on the "local" directory tree. But the actual remote location is dictated by the VMware host, and the only meaningful part of the "remote" location is the name `shared`.

You should be checking `ls /mnt/hgfs/shared` instead.

The use of this "NFS-like" syntax helps when you add this mount to the `/etc/fstab` file, like this:

```
.host:/shared  /mnt/hgfs/shared vmhgfs-fuse uid=1000,allow_other 0 0
```

if you have any `fstab` format checkers, they will note the presence of a `:` character in the first parameter, and will usually assume "it's a remote filesystem of some sort, so it is not possible to locally check whether or not this parameter is valid". For example, if you are using an editor with a syntax highlighting for `/etc/fstab`, the use of this "NFS-like" syntax prevents the editor from displaying this `/etc/fstab` line in ugly "incorrect syntax warning" color because `.host:/shared` matches no local block device and is not a valid `LABEL=` or `UUID=` specification.

Since your shell probably has no special filename completion procedures defined for commands beginning with `ls .host:...` , the shell is probably just ignoring the `.host:` part and processing the filename completion request exactly as if you had typed just `ls /`.

Comment: after I mount the `.host:/shared /mnt/hgfs/shared`,  there is no content in `/mnt/hgfs/shared`, if success there should have files in it.

Comment: Are there any error messages? Either after the `sudo vmhgfs-fuse ...` command, or in the VM's system logs?